# How can I check when an app comes back into the foreground from the background, but not from push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, lifecycle, appdelegate, application-lifecycle

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        var dat = JSON(data)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
            // app was already in the foreground
            println("App is in foreground")
            processNotification(dat)
        }else{
            // app was just brought from background to foreground via PUSH
            println("App brought back via PUSH")
            processNotification(dat)
        }
    }
```

This is how I check for push notifications. However, when if I send a push notification, the user misses it, and then opens the app via the icon? How can I check when the app was opened from the icon?

Comment: you mean, how to detect if the app is opened but there is an unopened notification hanging?

Comment: @Simon yes, I guess so.

Answer (score 19):

[The `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/) defines several methods that let you add code to several of your application's life cycle events.

Of specific interest to you would be the following:

- `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` - called just before the application has finished launching when the application was not already active in the background
- `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` - called just after the application has finished launching when the application was not already active in the background
- `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` - called just after the application has become active, this is called when the user launches from scratch, reopens from background, and also when a user returns from a temporary interruption (such as a phone call)
- `applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)` - this is called just before the application enters the foreground after having been in the background--it is immediately followed by the `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` call

This life cycle events can fire whether the user opened your application via a notification or by tapping on the icon.  As far as I know there is no way to tell for certain that the application was opened via tapping the icon.  You can know(ish) that the application wasn't opened via a notification, as the relevant "did receive notification" methods will never fire.  But this still allows the user two (at least) methods of opening the application: tapping the app icon *or* double tapping the home button and tapping the app to awake it from the background.

Comment: I'm guessing "applicationDidBecomeActive" is what I'm looking for right?

Comment: Probably.  It's easy enough to put break points or `println` in all of them and play around to see *exactly* how the life cycle works and figure out what you need exactly.

Comment: According to the reference pages there is a dictionary with keys in which you can find if there are still notifications hanging: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys